# Are "Are there any X that P is true of" questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Assuming that `X` is on topic for the Stack Exchange site in question, and `P` is a predicate which is complicated enough that searching for `X`'s where `P` is true using a search engine is difficult/unfruitful, is asking questions of the form "Are there any X that P is true of?" appropriate?

### Specific example

Are there any programming languages which implemented multiple inheritance by adding redundant data members (effectively implementing inheritance with composition)?

Comment: Can you give us a less abstract example please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's up to each site to decide. Some sites will be happy to allow these, others will consider them to be a kind of list or shopping question, and so will judge them off-topic.

Comment: Yes. In the specific example, the question would be closed on SO for asking to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource, but I'm pretty sure it might have been on topic in Programmers at one time.